# Raphael.js + qTip2 multiple tooltip loop issue

Tags: svg, tooltip, raphael, qtip2

I have Raphael + qTip2 working to make a Pie SVG + Tooltip hover.

The issue I am having is that when you hover over an SVG sector it shows the tooltips for every other sector in the code. I have tried moving the tooltip outside the loop, and pushed though an .each function but can't figure out the issue.

Basic markup as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="">Sector Title</a>
    <div>Tooltip</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JSFiddle should say it all:
http://jsfiddle.net/MUFV7/4/

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue using:

```
$(sector.node).qtip({
```